# How to Remove Returns from Open 2.1.0.2 Cart Account/Footer Area?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

How to Remove Returns from Open 2.1.0.2 Cart Account/Footer Area???

I tried looking online, but its for all the older versions, i tried them all and none remove it, its still there.

Thanks

Comment: Are you wanting to remove it for all visitors or just logged in customers?

Answer (score 0):

Open `catalog/view/theme/default/common/footer.tpl`

Remove this line:

`<li><a href="<?php echo $return; ?>"><?php echo $text_return; ?></a></li>`

Obviously if you're using a different theme, remove there as well.